# Não consigo utilizar usuários criados dinamicamente do Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Tenho um serviço de login no Spring Boot, composto pelas seguintes classes:

```
Models: Usuario.java e Login.java
Controller: UsuarioController.java e LoginController.java
Repository: UsuarioRepository.java
```

Usuario.java:

```
package com.alisystem.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Usuario {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String nome;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String login;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String senha;
    
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String perfil;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getSenha() {
        return senha;
    }

    public void setSenha(String senha) {
        this.senha = senha;
    }

    public String getPerfil() {
        return perfil;
    }

    public void setPerfil(String perfil) {
        this.perfil = perfil;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + (int) (id ^ (id >>> 32));
        result = prime * result + ((login == null) ? 0 : login.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((nome == null) ? 0 : nome.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((perfil == null) ? 0 : perfil.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((senha == null) ? 0 : senha.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Usuario other = (Usuario) obj;
        if (id != other.id)
            return false;
        if (login == null) {
            if (other.login != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!login.equals(other.login))
            return false;
        if (nome == null) {
            if (other.nome != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!nome.equals(other.nome))
            return false;
        if (perfil == null) {
            if (other.perfil != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!perfil.equals(other.perfil))
            return false;
        if (senha == null) {
            if (other.senha != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!senha.equals(other.senha))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public Usuario(long id, String nome, String login, String senha, String perfil) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
        this.login = login;
        this.senha = senha;
        this.perfil = perfil;
    }
}
```

UsuárioRepository.java

```
package com.alisystem.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.alisystem.model.Usuario;

@Repository
public interface UsuarioRepository extends JpaRepository<Usuario, Long> {

}
```

LoginController.java

```
package com.alisystem.controller;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.CrossOrigin;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.DeleteMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PutMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.alisystem.model.Login;
import com.alisystem.model.Usuario;
import com.alisystem.repository.LoginRepository;
import com.alisystem.repository.UsuarioRepository;

@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {
    
    @Autowired
    private LoginRepository loginRepository;
    private UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository;
    
    //public List<Usuario>listaOriginal = usuarioRepository.findAll();
    
    public static List<Usuario> lista = new ArrayList<>();
    static {
        lista.add(new Usuario(1, "Leonardo", "admin", "admin", "ADMIN"));
        lista.add(new Usuario(2, "Josiane", "gerente", "gerente", "GERENTE"));
        lista.add(new Usuario(3, "Alicia", "dentista", "dentista", "DENTISTA"));
        lista.add(new Usuario(4, "Carol", "func", "func", "FUNC"));
    }
    
    @GetMapping
    public List<Login> listar() {
        return loginRepository.findAll();
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<Login> getLoginById(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
      Optional<Login> login = loginRepository.findById(id);
      if (login.isPresent()) {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(login.get(), HttpStatus.OK);
      } else {
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
      }
    }
    
    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public Usuario adicionar(@RequestBody Login login) {
        
        loginRepository.save(login);
        
        Usuario usuario = lista.stream().
                filter(usu ->   usu.getLogin().equals(login.getLogin()) &&
                                usu.getSenha().equals(login.getSenha())).
                findAny().
                orElse(null);
        return usuario;
         
    }
    
    @PutMapping("/{id}")
      public ResponseEntity<Login> updateLogin(@PathVariable("id") long id, @RequestBody Login login) {
        Optional<Login> loginData = loginRepository.findById(id);

        if (loginData.isPresent()) {
          Login _login = loginData.get();
          _login.setLogin(login.getLogin());
          _login.setSenha(login.getSenha());
          
          return new ResponseEntity<>(loginRepository.save(_login), HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
          return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
        }
      }
    
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
      public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> deleteLogin(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
        try {
          loginRepository.deleteById(id);
          return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }
      }
    
    @DeleteMapping
      public ResponseEntity<HttpStatus> deleteAllLogins() {
        try {
          loginRepository.deleteAll();
          return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
        } catch (Exception e) {
          return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        }

      }
        
}
```

O serviço está funcionando, porém os usuários estão sendo criados estaticamente, em

```
static {
    lista.add(new Usuario(1, "Leonardo", "admin", "admin", "ADMIN"));
    lista.add(new Usuario(2, "Josiane", "gerente", "gerente", "GERENTE"));
    lista.add(new Usuario(3, "Alicia", "dentista", "dentista", "DENTISTA"));
    lista.add(new Usuario(4, "Carol", "func", "func", "FUNC"));
}
```

Eu gostaria de criá-los dinamicamente, fazendo algo assim:

```
public List<Usuario>lista = usuarioRepository.findAll();
```

Quando faço isso, dá um erro de compilação:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'loginController' defined in file [/Users/leonardo/Dropbox/Projetos/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.10.0.RELEASE/alisystem/target/classes/com/alisystem/controller/LoginController.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.alisystem.controller.LoginController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1316) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:524) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145) ~[spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) [spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:434) [spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:338) [spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) [spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1332) [spring-boot-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
    at com.alisystem.AlisystemApplication.main(AlisystemApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.5.2.jar:2.5.2]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.alisystem.controller.LoginController]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:225) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:87) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1308) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    ... 22 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.alisystem.controller.LoginController.<init>(LoginController.java:37) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_331]
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:212) ~[spring-beans-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

Alguém saberia me dar uma orientação neste caso?

Answer (score 1):

A dependência `UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository` não esta sendo mapeada.

Utilize a anotação `@Autowired` para injetar a depedência na classe.

Algo assim:

```
...
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {
    
    @Autowired
    private LoginRepository loginRepository;
    @Autowired
    private UsuarioRepository usuarioRepository;
    
    public List<Usuario>listaOriginal = usuarioRepository.findAll();
    ...
```